# Checking network availability continuously while rest of code is running separately

Tags: python

I am writing a code in Python to design a software application. I want to add following functionality in my code:

When user starts using software, a `ping()` function runs and tries to connect to internet to fetch some data. If network is not available then it should continuously check network availability to fetch the data. While that `ping()` is checking network continuously, I want my software application to do usual things.

My code is:

```
def ping():
    global lst1
    if network_connection() is True:
        links = lxml.html.parse("http://google.com").xpath("//a/@href")
        for url in links: 
            lst1.append(url)
    else:
        ping()

def network_connection():
        network=False
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com", None, 2.5)
            network=True

        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            pass
        return network
```

When application starts I call `ping()` and inside `ping()` function I am doing a recursive call. It is obviously wrong because in that case my code will stuck in this recursive call until network connection is available and application will not be initiated.

Is there anyway that I can do both things side by side: checking network availability and running rest of code at the same time?

Comment: Might multi-threading help you?

Comment: In case of network breakage, should your application do some other stuff, or wait?

Comment: It should do some other stuff in case of network breakage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need for continuous pinging, even that happens in a separate process/thread. You should use an [exponential backoff algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

And have the pinging process update a shared variable in the event of network failure to make sure your main process waits until the network is up/ or do offline work. For this, your code has to check the variable periodically during execution. I would suggest the [`multiprocessing` module for this task.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `while` loop to constantly check the network availability inside the `ping()` function. I'm totally agree with Blue Ice's answer about CPU usage when the code continuously check for internet connection. A single `time.sleep()` call from module `time` is enough to throttle down the loop.

```
import time

def ping():
    global lst1
    status = True
    while(status):
        if network_connection() is True:
            links = lxml.html.parse("http://google.com").xpath("//a/@href")
            status = False
            for url in links: 
                lst1.append(url)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1) #use 100 milliseconds sleep to throttke down CPU usage
```

Comment: Expecting a down connection to recover in 100ms is pretty optimistic. See exponential backoff in answer from @Karthikeyan. However, you avoided the tail recursion of the OP `def ping(): ... ping()` which will in Python eventually throw a `RuntimeError` for exceeding the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: @msw Thanks for noticing me and yes you're right, I was overoptimistic on that value. I wasn't into Exponential backoff because it causes significant delay between retries with only few iteration.

Comment: I'm not saying you must use EB, but I glad you know about it. You could ping a site every second and still not waste much bandwidth. However, if it's been down for 1s, then chances are high it will be down 2s, etc. Even if you clamp your polling interval at a max of 16s, that's still 16 times as polite as the alternative. Does politeness matter? That's not a technical question ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (that I can think of) to do this.

---

**1**:    Each process switches off for very short amounts of time. The ping() process will act, then the software will act, then the ping() process will act, etc.

However:

- Each process will be a bit laggy, depending on how fast the switching is.
- There will be wasted time switching between processes.

---

**2**: Use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library (python).

"multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package offers... ...concurrency. ...The multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine. It runs on both Unix and Windows."

- If the processes are unrelated, then they should each run quickly, and smoothly.

---

And a tip- don't try to **continuously** check for internet. That will make the processor very hot. Instead, put in small delays between each check.

Good luck!